# Plot_ly Scatterplot connecting lines how do most elegant?

Tags: r, plot, plotly, scatter-plot

I'm asking myself how to solve the following problem the most elegant. My data encompasses of some actual values and some proposed values. Right now I have data that looks like the reproducible example below:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

test_dt <- data.frame(Age=1:5, Key=c("Actuals", "Actuals", "Actuals", "Other", "Other") , Value=rnorm(5))

plot_ly(data = (test_dt %>% group_by(., Key) %>% arrange(desc(Age))), 
        x = ~Age, 
        y = ~Value,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines',
        color = ~Key,
        linetype = ~Key
) %>% layout(
  yaxis = list(
    title = "SD"),
  margin = list(top=100, b=50)
)
```

The output of this code looks like this:

how plot a dashed line where i drew the red arrow?

[image]

My solution so far is that I access the last value of my actuals and insert this value as a new row for my "other" line. But I don't think that's very elegant and sometimes, if no other values exist which can happen in my data depending on the inputs then I have a legend plotted for my "other" line without actually having one.

```
act_age_max <- filter(test_dt, Key=="Actuals") %>% .[["Age"]] %>% max
propval_names <-  filter(test_dt, Key!="Actuals") %>% .[["Key"]]
last_actual <- filter(test_dt, Age==act_age_max, Key=="Actuals") %>% .[["Value"]]
acts_year <- filter(test_dt, Age==act_age_max, Key=="Actuals") %>% .[["Year"]]

append_dt <- data.frame(Age=act_age_max, Key=propval_names, Value=last_actual)
plot_data <- rbind(test_dt, append_dt)


plot_ly(data = (plot_data %>% group_by(., Key) %>% arrange(desc(Age))), 
        x = ~Age, 
        y = ~Value,
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines',
        color = ~Key,
        linetype = ~Key
) %>% layout(
  yaxis = list(
    title = "SD"),
  margin = list(top=100, b=50)
)
```